# Camunda Work flow with single record with payload

Tags: bpmn, camunda

How to proceed for one sub process contains for multiple call activity for example of customer service one flow and agent service is another flow.
please any one can answer for this with example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. Please explain more.

In the fly-out menu of the call activity you can find the multi-instance marker on the top. After adding it to the call activity, you will see new properties, which allow you to define the collection that contains the list.

See: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/reference/bpmn20/tasks/task-markers/#multiple-instance